# Normalizing a continuous distribution

Tags: probability

I work at a help/tutoring center at my university.  Today a kid came in with this problem.  I've only studied math and haven't drifted into physics, but he had this problem:

Let $P(x)=Ne^{-\frac{|x|}{a}}$.  Then:

(a)  Find $N$ such that $P(x)$ is properly normalized.

(b)  Find $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle x^2 \rangle $

Attempt at solution:

$1=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Ne^{-\frac{|x|}{a}}=2\int_{0}^{\infty}Ne^{-\frac{x}{a}}=2\int_{0}^{\infty}Ne^{-u}a\,du=2Na\int_{0}^\infty e^{-u}du=2Na.$

So $N=\frac{1}{2a}$

I'm not sure how to do part (b).  The text, Robinett's Quantum Mechanics, was a bit beyond me.  Could I get some guidance on how to solve this problem...it seems really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a) you should check that the symmetry of $P(x)$ with respect to $x$ gives

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Ne^{-|x|/a} dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}Ne^{-x/a}dx$$

and then do a change of variable $\displaystyle u=\frac{x}{a}$

For part b) note that by definition $\displaystyle\langle f(x) \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)Ne^{-|x|/a}dx$ and that both $x$, $x^2$ and $P(x)$ have defined symmetry with respect to $x$ and you can exploit that symmetry to know the value of some of them (in particular $\langle x \rangle$ without actually computing the integrals

Comment: Is my $N$ now correct?

Comment: @Mark when you do the change $u=x/a$ the integral is that of $e^{-u}$ which happens to be $1$ for $u=0\to \infty$. Otherwise $N$ is correct

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your hint for part (b).  So $<x>=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}xNe^{-|x|/a}\,dx=2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}xNe^{-x/a}\,dx$.  After it is set up it looks like a pretty ugly integration by parts.

Comment: Using integration by parts I got $a^2N$ and $-2a^3N$.

Comment: Note that $P(x)$ is even on $x$ and $x$ is odd on $x$ so $P(x)x$ is odd on $x$, and the integral is on a symmetric interval with respect to $x$ so $\langle x \rangle = 0$

Comment: Since $x^2$ is even, I'm guessing this one will actually take some work?

Comment: Indeed, and you should integrate by parts. However $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x)x^2 dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} P(x) x^2 dx = 2N \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x/a}dx $ and now integrate by parts. Remeber that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}du=1$

Comment: I'm getting $2Na^3$.  I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: I think you're missing a factor of $2$

Comment: You are correct.  But now here is where I'm stuck.  By hand I get $4Na^3$.  Using mathematica I get the negative of that answer.

Comment: Mark, you should ask that question then at mathematica.SE http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/. Anyway note that $x^2 \geq 0 \hspace{0.2cm} \forall x \Rightarrow \langle x^2 \rangle \geq 0$